# How many Singular Value Decompositions can a matrix have?

Tags: linear-algebra

There's a rule when it comes to SVD's; that you have to fill in the diagonal of the $\Sigma$ in $U\Sigma V^T$ with singular values $\sigma$, ordering from greatest to least.

My first question:
**Why is that rule there?**

My more important second question **Can we rearrange the singular values and the vectors in $U$ and $V^T$ to get another SVD? Would these new SVD's be equally valid?**

Let's say there was a 3 by 3 matrix with 3 singular values; could I make 6 SVD's of that matrix?

Comment: The rule is there because it gives you the axes of the ellipsoid given by applying A to the unit ball in order of their length, which is a good way of ranking them for various reasons. Reordering gives a valid decomposition which is technically not an SVD. That said there are many singular value decompositions because the singular vectors are not unique. Indeed if the base field is the complex numbers then there are always continuum-many SVDs of any matrix.